# How to write a hive query to display all records if one particular record is present?

Tags: hiveql

I have to write a hive query to display a full table if a particular record is present in the table.

**For example:** 
I have a table customers 
( cust _name,cust_num,city,rating)

I have to display all the records if city San Jose is present in this table.
how can i write my query using select statement?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
    select a.* from customers a 
    inner join customers b on b.city = 'San Jose'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE city='San Jose'
```

Comment: Hi,
I need to display all the records in the table if it has San Jose.

Comment: Conditional logic is currently handled outside of HiveQL and is generally done via scripts.

Comment: Questioner is looking for all records if San Jose is present, this only returns the records related to San Jose.